# Dynamic routing by sub domain with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I override template URL based on sub domain?

*All of my sub domains point to the same doc root.*

*Base level domain:* **example.com**

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: 'views/example.com/home.html'});
```

*Sub-domain:* **sub.example.com**

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: 'views/sub.example.com/home.html'});
```

Partials should be indifferent to static / dynamic content. If a controller inside a partial is making service calls for data this interceptor shouldn't interfere with that.

Comment: Your template url looks to be just a relative path to the path of your index file. So to change domains (careful of same origin policy) you'd have to have these paths be absolute, possibly using a constant to configure them.

Comment: @xmltechgeek Sorry but I think you may have skipped over the part where the sub domains are pointing to the same doc root --- SOP has nothing to do with it. The problem here is that I need a way to detect domain, than intercept the `templateUrl` and change it for different sub domains.

Comment: Not sure your going to be able to do that with the default angular router. You should be able to use the templateProvider in the ui-router (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) from the angular-ui team to do this though. See https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#alternative-ways-to-set-the-template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A continuation fo this problem lead to **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095989/detect-if-resource-exists-behind-rewrite-rules-with-javascript-and-angularjs)**, but the answer is applicable for both:

I decided to go with a local stradegy for two reasons:

1. There is no additional overhead of XML request.
2. 404 messages wont polute console logs when resource doesn't exist.

**services.js**

```
factory('Views', function($location,$route,$routeParams,objExistsFilter) {

  var viewsService = {};
  var views = {
    subdomain1:{
      'home.html':'/views/subdomain1/home.html'
      },
    subdomain2:{

    },
    'home.html':'/views/home.html',
  };

  viewsService.returnView = function() {
    var y = $route.current.template;
    var x = $location.host().split(".");
    return (x.length>2)?(objExistsFilter(views[x[0]][y]))?views[x[0]][y]:views[y]:views[y];
  };

  viewsService.returnViews = function() {
    return views;
  };

  return viewsService;
}).
```

**controllers.js**

```
controller('AppController', ['$scope','Views', function($scope, Views) {    
  $scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess",function( $currentRoute, $previousRoute ){
    $scope.page = Views.returnView();
  });
}]).
```

**filters.js**

```
filter('objExists', function () {
  return function (property) {
    try {
      return property;
    } catch (err) {
      return null
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Easy and clean: I would inspect window.location in the function that sets up your routes, set a variable depending on the subdomain, then use that variable when setting up the routes. As in:

```
var isSubDomain = window.location.host.indexOf("sub") == 0
var urlPath = isSubDomain ? "sub.example.com" : "example.com";

...

$routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: 'views/' + urlPath + '/home.html'});
```

TL;DR: use JavaScript, not Angular

Comment: this is dirty considering there are already route providers that have the host name available to you. You can access `$location.host()` wihtin `.run()`

Comment: So Dan if he was using $location.host() it would be ok and easier to read than above right?