# detect if resource exists behind rewrite rules with javascript and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to overwrite portions of my single page app using only javascript and AngularJS.

Overwrites are based on subdomain.

*Every subdomain is pointing to the same doc root.*

**controllers.js**

```
controller('AppController', ['$scope','$route','$routeParams','$location', function($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location) {    
  $scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess",function( $currentRoute, $previousRoute ){
    render();
  });
  var render = function(){
    //Is it actually a subdomain?
    if($location.host().split(".",1).length>2){ 
      //Use subdomain folder if it is.
      var url = "views/"+$location.host().split(".",1)+"/"+$route.current.template;
      var http = new XMLHttpRequest();    
      http.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (http.readyState==4){
          //If there isn't an overwrite, use the original.
          $scope.page = (http.status!=404)?url:("views/"+$route.current.template);
        }
      }
      http.open('HEAD', url, true);
      http.send();
    }
    else{
      //Else we are on the parent domain.
      $scope.page  = "views/"+$route.current.template;
    }
  };
}])
```

**config.js**

```
config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    template: 'home.html'
  });
  $routeProvider.when('/services', {
    template: 'services.html'
  });
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppController">
<body>
<div ng-include src="page" class="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Because this is a single page app, when you hit a URL directly, it's going to `404`. That's why we apply rewrite rules on the server. In my case I'm using nginx:

```
location / {
   try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

This works great when I'm not on a subdomain, but then again I'm also not sending out an `XMLHttpRequest`. When I do use the subdomain, now we need to check for an overwrite.

**The tricky part here is that the rewrite rules are forcing the XMLHttpRequest to return a 200.**

*Ideas on how I can have my cake and eat it too?*

Comment: first thing to point out dont use XMLHttpRequest directly just use $http provided by angular meanwhile i check the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to go with a local stradegy for two reasons:

1. There is no additional overhead of XML request.
2. 404 messages wont polute console logs when resource doesn't exist.

**services.js**

```
factory('Views', function($location,$route,$routeParams,objExistsFilter) {

  var viewsService = {};
  var views = {
    subdomain1:{
      'home.html':'/views/subdomain1/home.html'
      },
    subdomain2:{

    },
    'home.html':'/views/home.html',
  };

  viewsService.returnView = function() {
    var y = $route.current.template;
    var x = $location.host().split(".");
    return (x.length>2)?(objExistsFilter(views[x[0]][y]))?views[x[0]][y]:views[y]:views[y];
  };

  viewsService.returnViews = function() {
    return views;
  };

  return viewsService;
}).
```

**controllers.js**

```
controller('AppController', ['$scope','Views', function($scope, Views) {    
  $scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess",function( $currentRoute, $previousRoute ){
    $scope.page = Views.returnView();
  });
}]).
```

**filters.js**

```
filter('objExists', function () {
  return function (property) {
    try {
      return property;
    } catch (err) {
      return null
    }
  };
});
```